# How do I get these animations to run out of sync?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have two characters I'm importing into Blender as FBX files. They have exactly the same mesh, armature, and animation clip; they just have palette-swapped textures making them into different characters:

[image]

We'll call them Blue and Red. I have a looping run animation attached to them, 21 frames long.  It works on both of them, but I don't like how they run in perfect unison; it looks artificial.  I want to offset Red's animation by 10 frames.  Basically, I want to take the first 10 keyframes of his animation, move it to the end, and then reposition all 21 keyframes so that they number 1-21 so that both Blue and Red run concurrently, but not in sync, in an animation that is still 21 frames long.

So far, I've tried selecting Red's armature, then selecting the first 10 keyframes in the Dopesheet and moving them to the end of the animation, then moving all 21 frames back into position, but this seems to have no effect on Red at all.  The only time I've seen a difference is when Red just starts his animation 10 frames later than Blue, which means that Red is just a frozen statue for 10 frames and then his animation is cut short by 10 frames. That isn't what I want, for obvious reasons.

How do I change Red's keyframes so that he performs the full animation concurrently with Blue, but starts at the original keyframe 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Normally" if you import two times an object, the animation should not be linked...so i wonder how that happened (and i assume you have a linked animation).

So just go to dopesheed -> action editor and you should see something like this:

[image]

important is the "2" which means, the exact same action is used by 2 objects.
Now just press the "2" button, which will make a real copy of that action and then you can move and modify it however you like.

if this doesn't work, please provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: Shouldn't one press the '2' to make single user copy, rather than "new action" button (the two sheets)?

Comment: sorry, of course, you are right, i corrected my answer

Comment: There is, in fact, a "2" there, but when I made a copy off that action and edited the copy, nothing changed.  Here's my blend file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/8yizbq2ixq5gr8a/RedBlue_Animation_Sync_Problem.blend/file

Comment: as i wrote, you have to move the action/keyframes after pressing "2". So e.g. select "Rumble.001", in action editor, hit "A" (select all), then G X and move your mouse, Then they are out of sync.

Comment: Again, nothing changed.  I'm trying to change the animation for the red character.  I selected all the keyframes and moved them 10 frames to the right, then selected the last 10 keyframes and moved them to the front of the animation.  There was no change in the red character at all.  When I go back to the timeline and run the animation, they are still perfectly in sync.  Is there some kind of "apply" action I'm missing?

Comment: ok, then please provide your changed file so i can check that out, thx.

Comment: maybe you made the same mistake as i did - if you run the animation the difference is really hard to see, but if you move the timeline with the cursor, you can see the difference. Also it might be helpful to color one leg in another color so you see which leg is in front.

Comment: Yeah, they are still 100% in sync.  Here's my revised blend file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/8jkqnlbwsoa44ys/RedBlue_Animation_Sync_Problem_02.blend/file

Comment: uhm...did u really select the armature, go to pose mode, and then move the animation? or did u keep object mode?

Comment: here all steps:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFw1w.gif
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uprzp.gif
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/paXbA.gif
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5YX3.gif

Comment: Whoa, that was it.  I didn't realize I had to be in Pose mode. I'm dumb.
Thanks.